# how can i get List view data into string array

Tags: android, list

how can i get my List view in to string array.
here is my code.

```
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    private ListView lv1;
    private Cursor openseting;  
    private List<String> lv_arr1;
    private  String lv_arr[];


DBConnect con1 = new DBConnect(getApplicationContext(), "colorCode");
        lv_arr1 = con1.selectList();

        lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr1));
```

In my dB class i used this method to get dynamic list.

```
public List<String> selectList() {      
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();   
 Cursor cursor = this.db.query("DisplaySettings", new String[] { "setName" }, null, null, null, null, null);        

           if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {      
              do {      
                 list.add(cursor.getString(0));     
              } while (cursor.moveToNext());        
           }
           if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {              
                  cursor.close();           
               }        
               return list;         
            }
```

XML layout:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background ="#FFFFFF"/>
```

Comment: Can you provide layout xml of ListView?

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Are you want to display ListView using ArrayList? or you want to get ArrayList from already displayed ListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `List list = new ArrayList();` to `ArrayList list = new ArrayList();` and also change return type of method `public List selectList()` to `public ArrayList selectList()`, I means instead of using List just use ArrayList everywhere.

Comment: I just cast like:  lv_arr = new String[lv_arr1.size()];
  int i =lv_arr1.size();
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
   lv_arr[j] = lv_arr1.get(j);
   System.out.println(lv_arr[j]);
  }